# ELASTICSEARCH - Aggregations not working on string field

Tags: kibana, opensearch

Elastic search extraction query is returning expected results in hints section of output but aggregation on field returning empty response

**output without aggregation**

```
{
    "_shards": {
        "total": 45,
        "failed": 0,
        "successful": 45,
        "skipped": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "logstash-wander-2022.08.17",
                "_type": "fluentd",
                "_source": {
                    "outboundResponseStatus": "SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE"
                },
                "_id": "Y2NlNjkzZmEtNjZlMi00NWY4LTllNWUtOWZmNWRhMjRkMzA3",
                "sort": [
                    1660695790244
                ],
                "_score": null
            },
            {
                "_index": "logstash-wander-2022.08.17",
                "_type": "fluentd",
                "_source": {
                    "outboundResponseStatus": "CONFLICT"
                },
                "_id": "OWNmZTFiOWEtYWQ2Mi00OGViLWFmY2EtMGQ4ZDg1NzRiYWNk",
                "sort": [
                    1660695781810
                ],
                "_score": null
            }
        ],
        "total": 25,
        "max_score": null
    },
    "took": 506,
    "timed_out": false
}
```

But adding below aggregation along with query returning empty response

```
"aggregations": {
        "outboundResponseStatus": {
            "significant_terms": {
                "field": "outboundResponseStatus",
                "keyed": true
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is the query

```
{
    "size": 500,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "search string",
                        "default_field": "*",
                        "fields": [],
                        "type": "best_fields",
                        "default_operator": "or",
                        "max_determinized_states": 10000,
                        "enable_position_increments": true,
                        "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                        "fuzzy_prefix_length": 0,
                        "fuzzy_max_expansions": 50,
                        "phrase_slop": 0,
                        "analyze_wildcard": true,
                        "escape": false,
                        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                        "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "message": {
                            "query": "search string",
                            "slop": 0,
                            "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "@timestamp": {
                            "from": "now-10m",
                            "to": "now",
                            "include_lower": true,
                            "include_upper": true,
                            "format": "epoch_millis",
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1
        }
    },
    "version": true,
    "_source": {
        "includes": [
            "outboundResponseStatus",
            "outboundUri",
            "message"
        ],
        "excludes": []
    },
    "stored_fields": "*",
    "script_fields": {},
    "sort": [
        {
            "@timestamp": {
                "order": "desc",
                "unmapped_type": "boolean"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How to get aggregations based on field in hints results?

Comment: What Elasticsearch version are you using? Do you have sample index mapping, sample documents and an example query you're using that you can provide to show a repro of your problem? Keyed doesn't seem to be an option for significant terms agg in 8.x https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-significantterms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-significantterms-aggregation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply
Kibana 6.7.1

Below is the query

Comment: Added query in the question.